# Does this structure has an identity element?

Tags: group-theory

I have the following structure and I'm wondering if it has an identity element:

$G(\mathbb{Q}, \Delta)$ where $\Delta$ is defined by $x\Delta y = x+y-3xy$.

In order to find the identity element I did the following:

$x\Delta e = e \Delta x = x \rightarrow x+e-3xe=x \rightarrow e(-3x+1)=0$

That's true when $e=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{3}$. Is it right to say that $0$ is the identity element? Or the structure doesn't have identity element because  $\frac{1}{3}$ also make the equation equal to $0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity element $\;t\;$  must fulfill that **for any element** $\;x\in \Bbb Q\;$ , it must be true that

$$x\Delta t=t\Delta x=x\iff x+t-3xt=t+x-3tx=x$$

and we get that $\;t=0\;$ fulfills this, and thus it's the identity element here. The element $\;\frac13\;$ doesn't make the cut, since for example:

$$2\Delta\frac13=2+\frac13-3\cdot2\cdot\frac13=\frac13\neq2$$

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing "identity element" with "null element".

$i$ is a (two-sided) identity element for an operation $*$ if it satisfies, for all $a$,

$$ a * i = i * a = a $$

$z$ is a (two-sided) null element for an operation $*$ if it satisfies, for all $a$,

$$ a * z = z * a = z $$

Your work shows that, for all $a$,

$$ a \Delta 0 = a \qquad \qquad \frac{1}{3} \Delta a = \frac{1}{3} $$

Comment: I don't think your definition of "null element" is correct at all (say, in rings, fields, etc.). I think you may be meant something else...

Comment: @DonAntonio: The additive identity element in a ring is also a multiplicative null element (i.e. in its multiplicative monoid). I've also seen it called a "[zero element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Identity_and_zero)", but I wanted to avoid confusion with the fact zero also used to name the identity element of additive groups.

Comment: Do you mean the operation * in your answer is the same in both and, in fact, would mean product (say, in rings)?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'm speaking about any magma. Though wikipedia suggests that the terminology is mainly used when the operation is associative.

Comment: But then I think that may be a rather confusing way to treat null elements, to say the least. "Identity" is usually the name reserved when an algebraic structure has only one operation, usually called product, or when it has more than one (say, rings) and then it is reserved for the mutliplicative unit. The null element or even neutral one is the "identity" (if you want) with respect to the addition operation (say, rings) which makes the structure an abelian group. Now, magmas can be unital...but as far as I know they aren't required to have a unit.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'm not sure how it's a confusing way to treat null elements, since it's the *definition* of null element. I specifically avoided the term "zero" because we are not in a case of rings where, by coincidence, the additive identity happens to be the multiplicative null, and I was deliberately trying to avoid invoking that picture.

Answer (score 0):

You started out correctly in setting up the equation 
$$x \Delta e = e \Delta x = x
$$
However, you forgot to mention the conceptual assumption behind that equation, and this seems to have thrown you off the track.

Instead, you should have started your argument like this:

- Suppose that $e$ is an identity element. It follows that for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have the equation
  $$x \Delta e = e \Delta x = x
  $$

As you proceed from this point, you must not lose track of your goal: to find a value of $e$ so that this equation is always true, no matter what $x$ is.

So, when you then go on to derive the equivalent equation
$$e(-3x+1)=0
$$
you can come to a very clear conclusion: there *is* a value of $e$ which makes this equation true no matter what $x$ is, namely $e=0$.